Counting number of unique values in one column if data in a 2nd column matches anything in a 3rd column
I have data that will be changing daily.
I'd simply like to get a count of unique values from the first column if the data in the same row of the 2nd column matches anything in the 3rd column located elsewhere.
For the most part the 3rd column to the side will stay the same and will be like an external whitelist and the first 2 columns will change daily.
I'd like to do this with a formula and not using the drop down filters
Example
For example, there are 3 possible locations in this. I want a count of how many locations (1, 2, or 3) that the desired colored product is found in.
Home contains both red and pink from the desired list.
Car contains only red from the desired list.
Even though there are 8 lines with the correct color or multiple colors for each location, I only want to know how many different locations contain those colors. In this case the answer should come back as 2.
I've tried multiple combinations of countif/index/match/etc but I have not figured out the proper way to do it. Also this will be used in Excel 2016.

Try countifs(), that allows multiple conditions

For Excel 2016 you would be looking at this method of doing unique counts. In your case you could use Countif to check that a colour appears in the list and then (since the locations are strings) use match to convert them into numbers as shown in the second example in the reference.
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(COUNTIF(Table2[Color],Table1[Products]),MATCH(Table1[Locations],Table1[Locations],0)),MATCH(Table1[Locations],Table1[Locations],0))>0))


As noted this should be confirmed with CtrlShiftEnter or you could use Sumproduct rather than Sum.

I was interested to read/follow the link, but it led to the MS UNIQUE page. Can you update? SU offers the SUMPRODUCT method, also. https://superuser.com/questions/189762/how-to-count-number-of-distinct-values-in-a-range

Apologies - link updated.

Much appreciated to both of you for your help. This method also works perfect in 2021 and hopefully as stated it works in 2016. I'll know tomorrow for sure. Thanks again

Since you're on 2016, I suggest you break down your process into separate columns. That should make this both maintainable and clear.

Add a column to your Data that seeks your Product flag in the list of Desired values. That will let you quickly label the match status for each row (below: MatchFlag column)
Add a column to your Desired flags table. Look up all the matches in the same ay (below: MatchData column)
Count the MatchData column

I've put your data into two Excel Tables: Flags and Data. That saves you from filling an unpredictable number of rows with your formulas.



Flags
MatchData

Labels
Values
MatchFlag

CountFlagMatches




red
TRUE

home
red
red

2


pink
TRUE

home
red
red




yellow


home
blue





green


home
blue








home
pink
pink







home
pink
pink







work
blue








work
blue








car
blue








car
blue








car
red
red







car
red
red





MatchData:
=IFNA(IF(VLOOKUP([@Flags], Data[MatchFlag], 1, FALSE)<>"", TRUE, FALSE), "")
MatchFlags:
=IFNA(VLOOKUP([@Values], Flags[Flags], 1, FALSE), "")
CountFlagMatches:
=COUNTIF(Flags[MatchData], "=TRUE")

Very much appreciated! There will actually be hundreds to thousands of rows for location and product and the desired flags list will be a lot longer. But this method will work perfect for me.

It works on the 2021 version at home, I'll have to make it work for 2016 if those 2 functions are not available as stated by Black cat. 2016 is the version my workplace has so I have no control over upgrading it. Some computers there are still using 2013 as well.

Argh - apologies. Sloppy of me! @Blackcat is completely right. I've edited that to swap out the XLOOKUP with VLOOKUP. To count UNIQUE, I've added a column on the Desired Flags table.
